# How to do a regex replace *and* capture in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a custom data format with open/close tags that I need to parse, e.g.:

```
<t1>  15  </t1>  <t2>  25  </t2>
```

Tags are never nested, but I don't know the tag names in advance.  I can't count on data conforming to XML (e.g. may have "<" or ">" characters between tags) so I can't use common XML parsers.  I can assume that close tags are always in place, and that there aren't duplicate tags in the same file.

I'm a perl guy, but I need to code this parser in python.  The easiest way to do this in perl is to do substitutions off the front, pulling the next open/close tag and everything inside, and then capturing the replaced text:

```
****************************************
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
%tags = ();
$_ = "<t1>  15  </t1>  <t2>  25  </t2>";

#              <   t1      >       15        <  /  t1  >  
while ( s| \s* <  ([^>]+)  >  \s* (.+\S) \s* <  /  \1  >  ||x ) {
    $tags{$1} = $2;
}

print "$_: $tags{$_}\n" for sort keys(%tags);

****************************************
```

I can't find any ability in vanilla Python to access captures after using re.sub(), and this whole problem seems *way* harder.  What am I missing here?

Comment: You just need to use a lambda inside the `re.sub` instead of a string replacement pattern. Please share your Python code.

Comment: Your question doesn't explain what you actually want to do with the data.  What do you want the result of your parsing process to be?

Comment: If you don't mind the double scan, you could first run `re.findall` to capture and and then run `re.sub` to replace.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  What is "a lambda"?  How would I do that inside the re.sub()?  I have no python code yet except for a variable "fileString" with the data that I need to parse.

Comment: @BrenBarn  The result needs to be a data structure that looks like this:  d[filename][tag] = value, e.g. d["file1.dat"]["t1"] = 15.

Comment: Ok, I see, you really need just a `re.findall`. See Rob's answer.

Comment: Yes, @WiktorStribiżew. Bryan asked an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). He doesn't really want to substitute-and-replace. He really wants to find all instances of the regex.

Comment: Aside: Consider using [tag:pyparsing].

Comment: @Bryan: Then why do you need to do any substitution at all?

Comment: @Robᵩ  I was trying hard to *not* ask an X-Y problem -- I just needed to parse the string, and mentioned that the perl substitution seemed to be the easiest method using the language I knew (update:  I need to edit the top-level question but SO won't let me =( ).  

Stefan's approach works and seemed the most simple, but I'm not sure I understand how they differ or under what conditions one would be preferred to the other, so I upvoted both.  Thank you!

Comment: Cool. I'm glad you have a solution that works for you.

Comment: Update:  I was trying hard to *not* ask an X-Y problem, but ended up doing just that.  My end goal is far more lofty (build a tool to manage/modify/report-on a specific type of file), and I thought I needed a replace/capture to accomplish my goal.  Wish they'd let me change the question so it would be more likely to be helpful to others.

Comment: @Bryan I think removing the replacing would change the meaning of the question too much (after all, it's explicitly mentioned in the title, even before the capturing, and the "and" is even emphasized). Also, while it may not be what you need, it may be what others need. It's not like it's a bad question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup (I kept your regex but added a few words to the string so we can see that the replacing actually works):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'front <t1>  15  </t1> middle <t2>  25  </t2> back'
>>> p = r'\s* <  ([^>]+)  >  \s* (.+\S) \s* <  /  \1  >'
```

If you don't mind the double scan, you could first run `re.findall` to capture and and then run `re.sub` to replace.

```
>>> dict(re.findall(p, s, re.X))
{'t1': '15', 't2': '25'}

>>> re.sub(p, '', s, flags=re.X)
'before between after'
```

Or use a function for the replacement, for example:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> re.sub(p, lambda m: d.update([m.groups()]) or '', s, flags=re.X)
'before between after'

>>> d
{'t1': '15', 't2': '25'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the substitution in Python. Use `re.findall()` or `re.finditer()`, like so:

```
import re
with open('input.txt') as input_file:
    data = input_file.read()

tags = {}
for match in re.finditer(r'<\s*(.*?)\s*>\s*(.*?)\s*</\1>', data):
    tags[match.group(1)] = match.group(2)
print tags
```

The `for` loop can be replaced by a dict comprehension. The following is equivalent to what I wrote above.

```
tags = dict(re.findall(r'<\s*(.*?)\s*>\s*(.*?)\s*</\1>', data))
print tags
```